# If a class is declared with a generic type parameter, and it's instantiated without specifying the type, does it default to Object?

Tags: java, object, generics, linked-list, queue

I've seen quite a few questions about whether or not it's possible to specify a default type if one isn't specified.  The answer to that appears to be no.  My question is, if your class header expects a type parameter, and you simply don't pass it one, what *does* it default to?  Object?  Take a simple Linked Node implementation of a Queue (abbreviated):

```
public class ListQueue<T> implements Queue<T>
{
   private Node<T> first;
   private Node<T> last;

   public void enqueue(T item)
   {
      Node<T> x = new Node<T>(item);
      if (isEmpty())
      {
         first = x;
         last = x;
      }
      else
      {
         last.next = x;
         last = x;
      }
   }

   public T dequeue()
   {
      if (isEmpty())
      {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Queue is empty");
      }
      T item = first.data;
      first = first.next;
      if (isEmpty())
      {
         last = null;
      }
      return item;
   }
}

public class Node<T>
{
   public T data;
   public Node<T> next;

   public Node(T data)
   {
      this(data, null);
   }

   public Node(T data, Node<T> n)
   {
      this.data = data;
      next = n;
   }
}
```

Then in my test driver, I am seemingly able to enqueue/dequeue any type of data:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   ListQueue myQueue = new ListQueue();  // key point: no type specified

   myQueue.enqueue("test");
   myQueue.enqueue(2);
   myQueue.enqueue(new Date());

   System.out.println(myQueue.dequeue()); // prints "test"

   int result = 2 + (Integer)myQueue.dequeue();
   System.out.println(result); // prints 4

   Date now = (Date)myQueue.dequeue();
   System.out.println(now); // prints current date
}
```

Of course I have to cast everything which defeats the purpose of generics, but is it really defaulting my data items to Objects to allow them all onto the queue?  That's the only explanation I can think of, but I'd like to confirm that since I can't find it concretely written out that that's the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you don't specify a type, it defaults to `Object`. **But** you should avoid using raw types and should use Generics as much as possible, because Generics provide tighter type checks at compile time.

You **must** know that the type parameter(s) are preserved only until Runtime, i.e. at Runtime type parameters are *erased* and this process is called [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: +1 and note that it defaults to its *upper bound*, which in this case is `Object`. So with `public class ListQueue<T extends Number>` it would default to `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

This was the way java 1.4 used to work. Generics was introduced as a part of java 1.5 so that we have better control over what we put into Collections and what we retrieve. This was done to minimise errors that could crop up during runtime.

To answer your question, it does default to object. Actually, it was always objects (atleast at runtime). The generics stuff that you use is only a safety net for us during compile time. Once the java class is compiled into byte code, all of the generics stuff is erased by the compiler. So your runtime code will look just like you never used generics at all.

Answer (score 0):

It does not "default" to anything. A raw type is different from any parameterized type.

`ListQueue` is not the same as `ListQueue<Object>`. Example:

```
ListQueue<String> foo;
ListQueue myQueue = foo; // compiles
ListQueue<Object> myQueue2 = foo; // doesn't compile
```

However, in terms of the parameter and return types of the methods of a raw type, they all become non-generic and T is reduced to the upper bound.